# how to insert second column of digits in the first in every cell in excel?

Tags: excel

I have 2 columns in excel:

[image: k]

however i want it to be 1 column of ranges:

```
250-424
425-463
```

etc

how to do it quickly? without copy-pasting every single digit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have listed columns "A" and "B", in column "C" (the next column to the right of column "B") enter this formula:

```
=A1 & "-" & B1
```

Then copy this formula down next to all of the values and you will have your desired result in column "C".

Here's a GIF to show you what I mean (look at the formula in the formula bar for reference):

[image]

Hope this helps.